# Deallocation error in Open CV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

My code

```
function(Mat m , ...){
//some code here
vector<Mat> chnls;

split(LA, chnls);

// code to take each channel and find the max in each r and channel

    for(unsigned int z  = 0 ;z<5;z++){

        //Mat m1 = chnls[z].clone();

        //find number of elements in m that are not 0 

        //the layer and max comparison
        Mat dest1; 

        compare(LAMax,chnls[z],dest1,CMP_EQ);
        //make it binary
        threshold(dest1,dest1,0,1,THRESH_BINARY);

        //the layer and thresh comparison
        Mat dest2;

        compare(chnls[z],Scalar(thresh),dest2,CMP_EQ);
        //make it binary
        threshold(dest2,dest2,0,1,THRESH_BINARY);

        //get the nonzero indexes
        bitwise_and(dest1,dest2,dest1);         

        vector<Point> reslts = cvFind(dest1,0,1);

        cout<<"z"<<z;

        for(int i=0;i<reslts.size();i++){
            lx.push_back(reslts[i].x);
            ly.push_back(reslts[i].y);

        }

        lr.push_back(rvals[z]);
    }

/*  for(int i=0;i<chnls.size();i++){
        chnls[i].release();

    }*/


result.push_back(lx);
result.push_back(ly);
result.push_back(lr);

return result;}
```

Whenever I run my code, at runtime following error appears.

```
HEAP[tester.exe]: Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 01270000, 01694E80 )
```

The error appears after the function is executed and before coming to the next instruction.

I searched and found out that this is due to some wild pointer(a pointer which points to nowhere) error. On looking at the Call Stack following details emerge

```
tester.exe!std::allocator<cv::Mat>::deallocate(cv::Mat * _Ptr=0x01694e80, unsigned int __formal=5)  Line 140 + 0x9 bytes    C++
tester.exe!std::vector<cv::Mat,std::allocator<cv::Mat> >::_Tidy()  Line 1139    C++
tester.exe!std::vector<cv::Mat,std::allocator<cv::Mat> >::~vector<cv::Mat,std::allocator<cv::Mat> >()  Line 560 C++
tester.exe!lower_eyelid_icb(cv::Mat m={...}, cv::Point_<int> center={...}, float iRadius=150.00000)  Line 413 + 0x2a bytes  C++
tester.exe!getEyelid(cv::Mat src={...}, cv::Mat * dst=0x0013f75c, cv::Point_<int> pupil={...}, int pRadius=31, int iRadius=150)  Line 858 + 0x48 bytes  C++
tester.exe!main(int argc=2, char * * argv=0x01275b20)  Line 248 + 0x55 bytes    C++
tester.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 582 + 0x17 bytes   C
```

If we look at the fifth line from the boottom, it looks like there is some error in deallocating a vector objects.

I have a vector object in the code which I am using inside a for loop. The declaration and usage is as follows.

```
vector<Mat> chnls; 
split(myMat,chnls) ; //myMat is a 2 Dimensional 5 channel object.
```

This is how I use chlns

```
compare(LAMax,chnls[z],dest1,CMP_EQ);
```

Then each channel is compared with matrix inside a for loop.

What could be the problem?

I am using VS2008 and OpenCv 2.3.

Comment: Can you post your code please?  Or a cut-down example that still demonstrates the problem if your code is too long.

Comment: Its just a function with the error after all the instructions of the function are executed. The error I think is when the function variables are deallocated. Also is having a vector of <Mat> means I have to deallocate each Mat individually.

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on so far.  Posting your actual code rather than a description of "just a function" can't possibly hinder people's attempts to help you.